# Enable submit button as soon as field is valid

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have the following model (with some non-relevant things removed):

```
import * as ko from "knockout";

export class RecipientsModel {
    private surveyId: string;
    editBulkAccounts = ko.observable([]);
    firstName = ko.observable("");
    debugData = ko.observable("");
    constructor() {};

    public addRecipients() {}
}
```

And this template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="recipients">
  <!-- ko with: recipient -->
  <form data-bind="submit: addRecipients">
    <div class="form-item form-type-textarea form-item-bulk-accounts">
      <label class="control-label" for="edit-bulk-accounts">Email addresses or mobile number<span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
      <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable textarea-processed resizable-textarea">
        <textarea data-bind="value: editBulkAccounts" class="form-control form-textarea required" id="edit-bulk-accounts" name="bulk_accounts" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="edit-submit--7" name="op" value="Mark participation" class="form-submit btn btn-fill btn-wd" data-bind="enable: editBulkAccounts().length">
  </form>
  <div data-bind="text: debugData">Test</div>
  <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

When I first load the page, my submit button is disabled as expected.  When I enter text into the textarea I want to submit button to immediately enable - even just one character is fine.  What is happening is that the submit doesn't enable until the text area loses focus, i.e. tab out or click elsewhere on the page.

Can I use knockoutjs to data binding to enable the submit button as soon as the textarea has any content?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the textInput binding instead of value on your textbox--it should update immediately

Comment: To be clear, in case others stroll along: `<textarea data-bind="value: editBulkAccounts"........>` Should be ``<textarea data-bind="textInput: editBulkAccounts"........>`.  Works like a charm, thanks!